# Can we secure JSON file data in client side or server side

Tags: php, google-api

I am using google apis and i have data in json file that can we access from browser easily, is there a way to prevent data

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('People API');
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_PeopleService::CONTACTS);
$client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth
```

Comment: you can do it using .htaccess

Comment: If you just want to protect a json file, put it outside of the document root. Then your PHP-code will be able to access it but no one can access it directly.